# Remove-Item : Cannot remove item because it is being used by another process

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, process, onedrive, process-explorer

The problem is very easy to understand.

Yesterday I have installed [en_visual_studio_2015_shell_isolated_x86_dvd_9fda4a05.iso](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/isolated-shell/) and the file is hanging on my Desktop.

[image]

When I try to delete it through `Remove-Item .\en_visual_studio_2015_shell_isolated_x86_dvd_9fda4a05.iso` the Terminal fires back with the error:

```
Remove-Item : Cannot remove item C:\Users\franc\OneDrive\Desktop\en_visual_studio_2015_shell_isolated_x86_dvd_9fda4a05.iso: The process cannot access the file
'C:\Users\franc\OneDrive\Desktop\en_visual_studio_2015_shell_isolated_x86_dvd_9fda4a05.iso' because it is being used by another process.
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-Item .\en_visual_studio_2015_shell_isolated_x86_dvd_9fda4a05.i ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Users\franc\...vd_9fda4a05.iso:FileInfo) [Remove-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveFileSystemItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

So I tried to find out what is handling that file:

```
$handleOut = handle
foreach ($line in $handleOut) { 
        if ($line -match '\S+\spid:') {
            $exe = $line
        } 
        elseif ($line -match 'C:\\Users\\franc\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\en_visual_studio_2015_shell_isolated_x86_dvd_9fda4a05.iso')  { 
            "$exe - $line"
        }
     }
```

But the answer was:

```
System pid: 4 \<unable to open process> -  7540: File  (R--)   C:\Users\franc\OneDrive\Desktop\en_visual_studio_2015_shell_isolated_x86_dvd_9fda4a05.iso
System pid: 4 \<unable to open process> -  7B18: File  (RW-)   C:\Users\franc\OneDrive\Desktop\en_visual_studio_2015_shell_isolated_x86_dvd_9fda4a05.iso
```

I ultimately used [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) and I found out that what is handling the file is OneDrive.

I stopped OneDrive but the problem persists.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is sheerly speculation, but it sounds like you need to unmount the iso: https://www.digitalcitizen.life/mount-unmount-iso-file-explorer/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the command with the `-Force` parameter?

`Remove-Item .\en_visual_studio_2015_shell_isolated_x86_dvd_9fda4a05.iso -Force`

Comment: Yes, I tried. It didn't work.